# Oracle RESTful Data Service config - keep extproc alive

Tags: oracle

We're using an Oracle Database with .Net stored procedures. For this to work, there is an entry to "EXTPROC" in the Oracle TNS configuration that handles the requests for the .Net procedures.

When I try to access such a procedure via SQLDeveloper directly from the database, the extproc process is created (if not already present) and then kept alive, this is working as intended since it's configured that way in the Windows registry.

However, when I route a call via ORDS, Oracle RESTful Data Services, it spawns a new process of the extproc instance (for each request) and after serving the request the extproc process is shut down.
This makes it very hard to debug (since I cannot attach to the process via remote debugger) and is also a big performance hit, increasing even simple requests duration from 50ms to 4 seconds.

It worked as expected on an 11g database, now it's running on a 12c.

Is there a known issue in ORDS 2.10 or a configuration I have not yet seen that would solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ORACLE REST Data Services is stateless (as is the HTTP protocol), that means each HTTP request retrieves a database connection from a pool, performs the request and when it's done returns the connection to the pool.

This is good for scalability, many many clients can share a limited pool of connections, each client only holds onto a connection for the duration of the corresponding HTTP request, the connection is reset at the end of each HTTP request. A pool of say 20 connections can serve hundreds and thousands of HTTP requests.

SQL Developer is stateful, when you create a connection in SQL Developer that connection is held by SQL Developer until you close the connection or the database kicks you out. If for the sake of argument your database can only accept 20 connections at a time, then if 20 folks are using SQL Developer and a 21st tries to connect, then they are out of luck.

Note that it is important that ORDS 'resets' each connection once it is finished with it and returns it to the pool. If this was not done then there would be information leakage across requests, one request might see state belonging to a previous state, which may cause bugs or constitute a security breach.

I'm guessing (I've never tried an external stored procedure) that this resetting of session state has the effect of blowing away the EXTPROC state, and causing a process to be created for each ORDS request.

I don't see a way around this apart from re-implementing the procedure in PL/SQL.

Comment: We're just having this issue in ORDS 2.10, before we used 2.0.9 where it kept the dll "hot". Both have not received any configuration except some URL maps and the initial database connection setup. I don't think it's an issue with the connections per se, that should work and makes sense just as you describe it. It's a matter of ORDS not keeping the libraries "loaded". This would be analog to IIS (or Tomcat, or Glassfish...) to reload the application from disk into memory for each single request and then unload it as soon as the single request has been served.

Comment: For example, this is configurable for .Net stored procedures (where it makes sense when debugging to unload the assemblies after each execution so they can be overwritten in a new deployment). It looks like this is the default behaviour for ORDS 2.10 and I just don't know where this could be... ORDS itself shouldn't actually know that it calls to a .Net stored procedure, since they're just wrapped within a regular pl/sql SP.

Comment: ORDS does not load the libraries. The database does. ORDS just executes the stored procedure via a regular JDBC call, it has no control or influence over how/when the database loads/executes external procedures, except for the fact that it resets the session state at the end of each call, to avoid data leakage, as I mentioned before. Has the database been upgraded, or patches applied? What about the .Net stored procedure support, has that been updated or re-configured?

Comment: Yes, the database has been upgraded. The old (good) behaviour was in an 11g environment, now it's on a 12c. ORDS went from 2.09 to 2.10. Is it linked to the "RecreateAppDomain" windows registry entry then? Because that's set to zero, to keep the CLR libaries loaded (which it does when called from SQLDeveloper, but not from ORDS). As far as I know, there's not a lot to configure for the .Net stored procedure support except the registry settings. Is there any other location where I can configure this behaviour?

Comment: I'm afraid I've no expertise on .Net and the database, you'll probably have to post a different question on the change in .Net stored procedure behaviour in 12c. 

I'd suggest asking in the Oracle Forums, this is the one for [.Net Stored Procedures](https://community.oracle.com/community/database/developer-tools/windows_and_.net/.net_stored_procedures):

https://community.oracle.com/community/database/developer-tools/windows_and_.net/.net_stored_procedures

Comment: For the benefit of others researching this topic, it might be useful to edit your original question to make it clear that the root of the change in behaviour is in the migration from 11g to 12c, not in the upgrade from ORDS 2.0.9 to 2.0.10